# Drawing points using openGL/SDL

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

i'm trying to track my hands then for each x,y i will draw a point on openGL window .

that's my code :

```
#include "GraphicsEffects.h"
#include "Errors.h"

GraphicsEffects::GraphicsEffects():
 _vboID(0)
{}


void GraphicsEffects::init(){
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
_window = SDL_CreateWindow("2D Painting", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,       SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED , 600, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

if(_window == nullptr){
    fatalError("SDL window could not be created! "); }


SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(_window);
if(glContext == nullptr) {
    fatalError("SDL_GL context could not be created!");
}

GLenum error = glewInit();
if(error != GLEW_OK){
    fatalError("Could not initialize glew!");
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

if(_vboID == 0){
    glGenBuffers(1, &_vboID);
}

_colorProgram.compileShaders("Shaders/color.vert", "Shaders/color.frag");
_colorProgram.addAttribute("vertexPosition");
_colorProgram.linkShaders();

}


void GraphicsEffects::draw(int x, int y){
int pointData[2];
pointData[0] = x;
pointData[1] = y;

glClearDepth(1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

_colorProgram.use();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboID);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(pointData), pointData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_POINT, 0, 1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

_colorProgram.unuse();

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);


}
```

For Shaders/color.vert : "vertex shader file"

```
#version 130

in vec2 vertexPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position.xy = vertexPosition;
    gl_Position.z = 0;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

for Shader/color.frag: "fragment shader"

```
#version 130 

out vec4 color ;

void main() {
    color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

i expected i will get points with my (x,y) movements but nothing appears on the window !

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
glDrawArrays(GL_POINT, 0, 1);
```

will generate an `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error and do nothing else. The correct value is `GL_POINTS`, not `GL_POINT`.

You should really add error checking, at least for development builds. If possible, have a look at the [debug output functionality](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Debug_Output) of newer OpenGL versions.

Comment: thank you for your reply, 
but i still have nothing on the window!

Comment: well, what are the coordinates you are using? Since you don't do any transformations in the VS and leave `w` at 1, you will directly draw in normalized device space, which is [-1, 1]. Since you use integer coordinates, you are very unlikely to see anything, except for the (0,0) case, which should end up in the window center.

Comment: ok, i changed my x,y to float and tried some values like ( 0.4 , 0.7) and nothing appears !